# problema al encontrar el minimo elemento par de un array

Tags: c

estoy intentando hacer una funcion en C que retorne el elemento mas chico y par de un arreglo de nuumeros enteros. pero siempre que la llamo en el main me da como resultado -2. No puedo encontrar el error:

```
int minimo_pares(int a[], int tam){
int i, min, temp = 0;
while(i<tam){
    if((a[i] % 2 == 0)&& a[i]{
        min = a[i];
    } else{
        if(min>=a[i] && (a[i]%2 == 0) && a[i]{
            temp = a[i];
            min = temp;
        }
    }
} i = i + 1;
return min;
```

}

Comment: ¿Puedes corregir tu código? ¿Qué es lo que intentas evaluar aquí `(a[i] % 2 == 0)&& a[i]`? ¿Cuál es el input que le estás mandando al arreglo. De acuerdo a tu lógica, si el arreglo tiene un número par negativo, ese va a ser el menor, ya que `-2` es menor a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

A ver, vayamos por partes, el código que has adjuntado presenta varios errores de sintaxis que te van a lanzar un error al compilar, una versión funcional de tu código sería:

```c
int minimo_pares(int a[], int tam) {
    int i, min, init;
    i = min = init = 0;
    while(i < tam) {
        if(a[i] % 2 == 0){
            if (!init) {
                init = 1;
                min = a[i];
            } else if (min >= a[i]) {
                min = a[i];
            }
        }
        i++;
    } 
    return min;
}
```

Algunos errores a destacar en tu código podrían ser:

- `i = i + 1;` esta línea debería estar dentro del while, para que se vaya incrementando `i` en cada iteración.
- `&& a[i]`, no tengo muy claro que quieres hacer con esto, pero ignorando el echo de que te falta cerrar el paréntesis del `if`, si lo que quieres es comprobar que no sea 0, funcionaría.
- `int i, min, temp = 0;`, depende del compilador que utilices y la versión de c/c++, las variables `i` y `min` no estarán inicializadas y tendrán valores "aleatorios", inicialízalas bien como he hecho yo o bien `int i = 0, min = 0, temp = 0;`.

Comment: enormes gracias! pude comprender al fin los errores

Answer (score 0):

Una formulación más simple sería:

```
int minimo_pares(int a[], int tam) {
    int min = -1;
        
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) 
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0 && (min == -1 || a[i] < a[min])) 
            min = i;
        
    return a[min];
    }
```

En lugar de guardar el menor valor par en `min`, lo que guardamos es su **índice**. Si partimos con `min = -1`, entonces podremos detectar el primer valor par. Luego será comparar cada nuevo valor par contra el mínimo a la fecha.

#### Demo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int minimo_pares(int a[], int tam) {
    int min = -1;
        
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) 
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0 && (min == -1 || a[i] < a[min])) 
            min = i;
        
    return a[min];
    }

int main() {
    int arr[10] = {10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5};
    
    printf("%d", minimo_pares(arr, 10));
}
```

produce:

```
2
RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```